# What happened to "gcloud components update gae-go"?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

When following instructions to install (update) AppEngine Go, "gcloud components update" fails indicating that "gae-go" is not an option.

Comment: when you say "following the instructions", mind pointing me to the page?

Comment: What do `gcloud --version` and `gcloud config list` report? (I've not seen nor tried go with gcloud but I see that the other runtimes now have IDs of the form `app-engine-python`, etc.)

Comment: @Patrice - https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine?_ga=1.217677328.721434531.1412796734  Select Go. Go to step 3, substep 4.

Comment: @tx802 - I thought "app-engine-go" might be a hidden option, but no such luck.

Comment: @DougKnesek indeed, I did not think of that one. Recently there has been a move in gcloud. I'll post an answer that should be able to guide you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `gcloud` tool no longer bundles the `gae-go` component.  It also no longer provides or supports the `dev_appserver.py`, `appcfg.py`, or `goapp` tools.

For now, please download the [stand-alone Go App Engine SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads) if you are developing "classic" Go on App Engine apps.

If you wish to develop "Managed VM" Go apps, then you will continue to use the `gcloud` tool.

[This documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted) has updated information about the differences.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using "v1" apps (like the tutorial on the console shows you to use), you need to download the [stand alone Go App Engine SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads) instead.

If you are using a "v2" apps (Managed VM app), then the instructions are okay and work.

In your case, since you are a on a v1 app, you'll need to use "goapp serve" or "goapp deploy" to run as devserver and upload your code.